# How to remove a silent chunk from split chunk in python?

Tags: python, audio, split

I have some speech audio files that I want to split into 30 sec chunks, here is the code

```
# Split Audios to 30 sec
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import make_chunks

myaudio = AudioSegment.from_file('wav.audios/file_Name.wav' , "wav")
chunk_length_ms = 30000 # pydub calculates in millisec
chunks = make_chunks(myaudio, chunk_length_ms) #Make chunks of one sec

#Export all of the individual chunks as wav files

for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
    chunk_name = 'parts/chunk{0}.wav'.format(i)
    print("exporting", chunk_name)
    chunk.export(chunk_name, format="wav")
```

One chunk of the audio is always a silent chunk (the last one), I want python to detect it and delete it, so I end up with chunk of files that are not silent. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply delete the last chunk using - `del chunks[-1]` as shown below.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import make_chunks

myaudio = AudioSegment.from_file('wav.audios/file_Name.wav' , "wav")
chunk_length_ms = 30000 # pydub calculates in millisec
chunks = make_chunks(myaudio, chunk_length_ms)
del chunks[-1]

for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
    chunk_name = 'parts/chunk{0}.wav'.format(i)
    print("exporting", chunk_name)
    chunk.export(chunk_name, format="wav")
```